# How to log exception when transactions roll back in Hibernate and JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, logging, transactions, stack-trace

I use Hibernate with Spring and JPA in my project. The code uses annotation-driven transaction (using @Transactional annotation to support transaction) in service layer. The transaction manager is org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager. When a exception occurs in any @Transactional annotated method, current transaction will rollback, silently.

I wonder if I want to log the exception and its stack trace when a transaction roll backs, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can craete a custom HibernateTxManager extending the current one. and then override the method doRollBack() of it and write your Logger exception to get the trace from there.